# Can't deploy project in visual 2012 pro with device lumia 520

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a problem , I can't fix this.
I deploy project with device (lumia 520) , but visual push notification: windows phone 8 phone was detected. But , my phone is really plug in my computer , and i can access phone's folder.
My phone didn't lockscreen.
Phone's driver has installed.
You can see in the picture:

http://i.upanh.com/rchnbi

I was restarted my phone for 10 times , but it's still connected.

Help me resolve this problem , thanks

Comment: I don't have post enought in order to put image into my post , you can click link above to watch image.
My phone registed devloper unlock , I was using win 8 pro 64 bit

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried to deploy your app to an Windows Phone Emulator?

If your app succesfully deploying to Emulator, I can say your connection of your phone is having problem. But, if you can not deploy your app neither phone nor emulator, it could be about VS2012 or SDK.

So, I sugges you to remove your phone from your computer (Open Device Manager and remove your app (dont forget to unplug it). And then reconnect your phone again.

So, try these and please tell me the results. I was had some problems like yours.

And also, maybe you can check your device's registration status (developer registration) If yes, please try unregister and register it againg for development (http://prntscr.com/2fehv1)

Answer (score 0):

Do a soft reset to your device and restart VS2012 again to solve this problem. (To do this: press and hold the power button and volume down button for about 10 seconds)

Comment: I do this for 10 times , but my phone still not connected to visual. Do you know this problem is visual , sdk or my phone ?